# Converting -dec to HEX to in php

Tags: php

I need to convert a dec to Hex like following:

```
echo $val = dechex(-29338);
result = ffff8d66
```

May I know how to "throw away all those ffff and finally return me 8d66? I am using bitwise like following but it doesn't help

```
echo  $val & 0xFFFF ;
```

Comment: That will just mangle the number. What's the purpose of the transformation?

Answer (score 2):

`dechex()` result is as string so bitwise operation will not work. Use string function like `str_replace()` or `substr()`

In your case, a negative number is a signed integer so the `FFFF` are legit. Removing it will result in `8d66`, and `8d66` is equal to 36198 !